# MDX query - YTD producing incorrect result due to where

Tags: mdx

I want to return the YTD (i.e. Jan to Current period) values for a number of periods (e.g.  Mar 2012 to Jan 2013). However understandably, when I apply the where clause to restrict it to 'Mar 2012 to Jan 2013' we lose the Jan and Feb values from the YTD. Below is some example code:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Last Day of Month] AS 
    TAIL(EXISTING [Date].[Date].[Date].MEMBERS).ITEM(0).ITEM(0).MEMBER_CAPTION
  MEMBER [Measures].[Calculate YTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      periodstodate(
        [Date].[Calendar].[Year],[Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember
      )
     ,[Measures].[Internet Total Sales]
    ) 
SELECT 
  { 
   [Measures].[Last Day of Month]
   ,[Measures].[Internet Total Sales]
   ,[Measures].[Calculate YTD]
  } ON COLUMNS,
  [Date].[Calendar].[Month] 
  ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works Internet Sales Model]
WHERE 
(
 [Date].[Date].&[2012-03-01T00:00:00]:
 [Date].[Date].&[2013-01-01T00:00:00]
);
```

Result of above query with incorrect YTD:

```
3-Mar   $373,483.01

4-Apr   $773,818.62

5-May   $1,132,696.51

6-Jun   $1,687,856.65

7-Jul   $2,132,414.88

8-Aug   $2,656,332.26

9-Sep   $3,142,509.71

10-Oct  $3,677,669.20

11-Nov  $4,215,624.71

12-Dec  $4,840,126.88

1-Jan   $29,456.25
```

Values I would like the query to return (Correct YTD Values):

```
    Calculate YTD

3-Mar   $1,375,841.32

4-Apr   $1,776,176.93

5-May   $2,135,054.82

6-Jun   $2,690,214.97

7-Jul   $3,134,773.20

8-Aug   $3,658,690.58

9-Sep   $4,144,868.03

10-Oct  $4,680,027.51

11-Nov  $5,217,983.03

12-Dec  $5,842,485.20

1-Jan   $29,456.25
```

Comment: if my answer is the answer maybe you could un-check the incorrect answer and check mine? - this helps future users (and helps me to try to get over the 20k line!)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not too sure if either of these approaches will work but anyway here goes...

**`Sub-select`**

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Last Day of Month] AS 
    TAIL(EXISTING [Date].[Date].[Date].MEMBERS).ITEM(0).ITEM(0).MEMBER_CAPTION
  MEMBER [Measures].[Calculate YTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      periodstodate(
        [Date].[Calendar].[Year],[Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember
      )
     ,[Measures].[Internet Total Sales]
    ) 
SELECT 
  { 
   [Measures].[Last Day of Month]
   ,[Measures].[Internet Total Sales]
   ,[Measures].[Calculate YTD]
  } ON COLUMNS,
  [Date].[Calendar].[Month] 
  ON ROWS
FROM 
( 
SELECT
  [Date].[Date].&[2012-03-01T00:00:00]:
  [Date].[Date].&[2013-01-01T00:00:00] ON 0
FROM [Adventure Works Internet Sales Model] 
);
```

**`HAVING` clause:**

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[Last Day of Month VALUE] AS 
    TAIL(EXISTING [Date].[Date].[Date].MEMBERS).ITEM(0).ITEM(0).MEMBERVALUE 

  MEMBER [Measures].[Last Day of Month] AS 
    TAIL(EXISTING [Date].[Date].[Date].MEMBERS).ITEM(0).ITEM(0).MEMBER_CAPTION
  MEMBER [Measures].[Calculate YTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      periodstodate(
        [Date].[Calendar].[Year],[Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember
      )
     ,[Measures].[Internet Total Sales]
    ) 
SELECT 
  { 
   [Measures].[Last Day of Month VALUE]
   ,[Measures].[Last Day of Month]
   ,[Measures].[Internet Total Sales]
   ,[Measures].[Calculate YTD]
  } ON COLUMNS,
  [Date].[Calendar].[Month] 
  HAVING 
    (
      [Measures].[Last Day of Month VALUE] >=CDATE('3/1/2012')   
      AND  [Measures].[Last Day of Month VALUE] <=CDATE('1/1/2013')
    ) 
  ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works Internet Sales Model];
```

Comment: @phil .... if this is the answer maybe you could un-check the incorrect answer and check this one - this helps future users (and helps me to try to get over the 20k line!)

Comment: @whytheq- Sorry new to this I thought I could tick both yours and the other guys as they are both correct. I have ticked yours as you were the first poster (I assume this it correct etiquette?). However I think you need to remove the sub set option as this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @phil no problem phil. Glad the answer helped.

Comment: Hmmm. Some one, without the guts to explain themselves had marked my answer down... After the question got marked as the correct answer which is a bit odd as that seems to indicate that it is the correct answer!

Comment: Definitely was not me. it is correct from my point of view. Thanks again!

Comment: Not accusing you Phil. Don't think you've got enough points to mark posts down.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use YTD function. It will give you the correct result with or without where clause.

(AdventureWorks 2014, YTD for Internet Sales Amount measure)

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Calculate YTD] AS 
   AGGREGATE(YTD(), [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])
SELECT 
  { 
  [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
  ,[Measures].[Calculate YTD]
  } ON COLUMNS,
  [Date].[Calendar].[Month] 
  ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE 
(
 [Date].[Date].&[20120301]:
 [Date].[Date].&[20130101]
);
```

or with the PeriodsToDate:

```
WITH 

   MEMBER [Measures].[Calculate YTD] AS 
    sum
    (
      periodstodate(
       [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year],   
            [Date].[Calendar].currentmember
      )
     ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
    ) 


SELECT 
  { 
  [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
  ,[Measures].[Calculate YTD]
  } ON COLUMNS,
  [Date].[Calendar].[Month] 
  ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE 
(
 [Date].[Date].&[20120301]:
 [Date].[Date].&[20130101]
);
```

Both queries return the same results:

```
March 2012  $1,375,841.32
April 2012  $1,776,176.93
May 2012    $2,135,054.82
June 2012   $2,690,214.97
July 2012   $3,134,773.20
August 2012 $3,658,690.58
September 2012  $4,144,868.03
October 2012    $4,680,027.51
November 2012   $5,217,983.03
December 2012   $5,842,485.20
January 2013    $857,689.91
```

Comment: Hi Vldmrrdjcc, Thanks so much for your answer! It is correct for the problem I explained. However my financial year here is really July-June. So I don't think I can use the YTD function, as it relies on the year level in the time hierarchy. The only work around I know of uses the periodstodate as above. Is there some way of not restrucung it by the where clause?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to achieve, because when I use your formula  like this  MEMBER [Measures].[Calculate YTD] AS 
    sum
    (
      periodstodate(
       [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year],   
            [Date].[Calendar].currentmember
      )
     ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
    )   I am also getting the same results as I got with YTD, so again you will have the same numbers which are not affected by the where clause